# Counting all comma separated values in multiple cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, formula

I want to count all days that employees take throughout the year and add them up to keep track of how many days have been used. I want a formula to count the dates in the format `x/xx` separated by a value. In this example, I have January with a cell showing `1/17`, `1/18`, `1/19`, `1/20`. I want this formula to also be able to add 11 other cells for all months of the year.

I tried

```
=COUNTA(SPLIT(A5+B5+C5+D5+E5+F5+G5+H5+I5+J5+K5+L5, ",")) - NOT(LEN(A5+B5+C5+D5+E5+F5+G5+H5+I5+J5+K5+L5))
```

but that didn't work.

Does anyone have a solution that's a little cleaner?

[One of twelve cells that need to be added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76dzm.png)

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=counta(iferror(split(textjoin(", ",1,A5:L5),",")))
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm this is a good start! The problem is that I need to get specific cells in the range, I should have clarified. I'm trying to separate out all sick days, personal days, and vacation days for the year so the formula really looks more like A5+D5+G5 etc...

Also, when I use the formula you provide it spits out a 1 even if there are no dates in a cell. Is there a way to spit out 0 for any cells that are empty?

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.